# Sending user to a page created based on their POST request in Django

Tags: django, web-applications, redirect

I have a form in which the user selects a few items to display on "the following page". This selection is always unique, and we will store each set of selections made using a model, indexed by the `id` as is par with Django models. When the user selects her choices and `POST`s using the submit button, I would like for our application to store her selections in the model, and then render a page with the id of the model so that the user can get back to the page she created at any point with a simple `GET` request.

For example, the user goes to `/coolapp/selectprefs/`, makes a few selections, and clicks submit. The user should then be taken to `/coolapp/selections/42` given that when the user submitted and created the record, the record was given an `id` of `42`.

What I don't understand is how to send the user to "the following page" as a response (e.g., `/coolapp/selections/42` in the above example) after she clicks the submit button. Taking a user to a page of a unique ID based on what she entered seems like a common task (e.g., it will happen when I click the button to submit this question on SO), but I'm not sure how to go about doing it, and would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Return a [HttpResponseRedirect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) from your view that handles the POST.

Comment: Thanks, Brian! This got me on the right track. It looks like there's a nice shortcut for this, too: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about this new shortcut. :)